# Dynamically added data not loaded in TextBoxes in jQuery mobile/java script. data has [object HTMLInputElement]  instead of value

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implemented an application for **iphone and android in phoneGap using jQueryMobile**

My app is already completed for single html page aND works fine.

now for better performance i used to implemented in **separate multiple html files**.

*in a js file i have implemented code for edit employee information as follows*.

```
 EditInfoButton.click(function() 
{
         var row = backupInformation;
         alert(row.Emp_Name);
         $('#editEmpName').val(row.Emp_Name);

         ...

         ...

    });
```

here **`alert(row.Emp_Name);`** ***popups correct result when click the button but not** displayed in textbox*

And in a html file for edit page i have implemented text box using jQuery mobile as follows

```
using **`id = "editEmpName"`**
```

text box in One of my Html:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" >
          <label for="Empname"  class="ui-input-text" ><b>Employee Name</b></label>
            <input name="Empname" type="text"  id="editEmpName"/>
  </div>
```

But in html page one button action  **`onClick="alert(editEmpName)"`**  popus **[object HTMLInputElement]**

y this **[object HTMLInputElement]** how to get my value from `editEmpName`

**and hows'd i get the correct value in texbox**

Answer (score 0):

The code which produces the incorrect alert is displaying the HTML element itself, rather than the value of the element. Where does the variable `editEmpName` get initialised in your JavaScript? If its set to the input element with id 'editEmpName' then you can just do

```
onClick="alert(editEmpName.value)"
```